# Scala type mismatch on value function

Tags: scala

I have an application with a case class of `case class Test(name: String, flag: Boolean)` and while trying to compile I'm getting the following error:

```
[error]  found   : String => Boolean
[error]  required: Boolean
```

Here is the code that is throwing the error:

```
val flag = (input: String) => try {
  if(input.toInt == 1) true else false
} catch {case e: NumberFormatException => false}
```

Is it possible to fix this or do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't give an error by itself. However, if you try to instantiate a `Test` by doing `Test("some name", flag)`, it will fail because `flag` is a function. The `Test` class requires it to be a boolean.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like `Test("some name", "1")` and want to return an object of `Test("some name", true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `flag`-function you have created when you instantiate a new object of type `Test`. Like this:

```
Test("some name", flag("1"))
```

Another option is to overload the constructor in the `Test`-class:

```
case class Test(name: String, flag: Boolean)
    def this(name: String, input: String) = this(name, Test.flag(input))
}

object Test {
    def flag(input: String) = (input: String) => try {
        if(input.toInt == 1) true else false
    } catch { case e: NumberFormatException => false }
}
```

You can then just call `Test("some name", "1")` to get `Test("some name", true)`.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be working either. It's throwing a `error: not found: value flag` error.

Comment: While the overloaded constructor example you provided is still throwing errors, I was able to get call my `flag` function and it worked - I fat fingered something the first time.

Comment: Oops, the flag-method should have been in the companion object of `Test`.